# How to deserialize JSON with @JsonCreator and @JsonGetter

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have the JSON looks like the following:

```
{
  "name":"John",
  "n_age":500
}
```

and I have a class `Person`:

```
public class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    @JsonCreator
    public Person(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = 100;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonGetter("n_age")
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

I need to deserialize and serialize it, but when I'm trying to deserialize this JSON I get unexpected result.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Person person = mapper.readValue(args[0], Person.class);
    System.out.println(person.getAge()); // I got 500, but I expect 100.
}
```

Why when I'm trying to deserialize it the @JsonGetter annotation is used for it?
How can I disable @JsonGetter annotation when I try to deserialize the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `@JsonGetter` is used as is currently, it will map property `n_age` to field `age`. To citate the [docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonGetter.html) - *It can be used as an alternative to more general JsonProperty annotation (which is the recommended choice in general case).*

To fix this behaviour, you need to:

1. Tell jackson to ignore property `n_age`, otherwise you will get exception for unrecognized property not marked as ignorable - `@JsonIgnoreProperties("n_age")`.
2. Tell jackson to allow getters for ignored properties(basically make it readonly) - `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"n_age"}, allowGetters = true)`

In the end, `Person` should look like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"n_age"}, allowGetters = true)
public class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    @JsonCreator
    public Person(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = 100;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonGetter("n_age")
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: If I need to serialize this object later, I can't get property ```n_age```. I set up ```@JsonGetter``` annotation for serialization this object later.

Comment: @John Check editted answer, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for fixing my issue, maybe it's a bad way, but it works for me as well. I'm ignoring the `n_age` property during deserialization and allowing getters during serialization.
Thanks a lot @Chaosfire for the help!

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"n_age"}, allowGetters = true)
public class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    @JsonCreator
    public Person(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = 100;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonGetter("n_age")
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```